# achartengine change location of origin

Tags: android, orientation, achartengine

I'm drawing a BarChart with AChartEngine on Android.

I made the chart horizontal by changing the orientation of the `XYMultipleSeriesRenderer`:

```
mMSRenderer.setOrientation(Orientation.VERTICAL);
```

(it seems counter-intuitive that horizontal is set with `Orientation.VERTICAL`, but that's not the point of my question).

The origin of the plot is on the top left corner, while I would like it in the bottom left, so that values go increasing from the bottom to the top.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible with AChartEngine as it is out of the box.

However, you can try to put your data in your dataset in a reversed order and add custom labels instead of the default ones.